# StreamReader: Why reading all text in one line?

Tags: .net, vb.net, webclient, streamreader

i need little help.
First sorry for my terrible English.
So, im working on my project coded in .net, im using Visual Studio 2015.
I trying to get raw text from url to textbox. 
When i say raw i mean https://example.com/files/SomeText.txt

So what i want is to get txt to my textbox like this (Same what i see in browser)

```
information11 data1 number1
information11 data1 number1
information11 data1 number1
information11 data1 number1
```

but it appears like this

```
  information11 data1 number1 information11 data1 number1 information11 data1 number1 information11 data1 number1
```

Here is my code

```
Dim adrs As String = "https://example.com/files/SomeText.txt"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(adrs))
TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: Are you sure that your textbox allows multiline text?

Comment: Also, is there any reason you're not using client.DownloadString()?

Comment: Yes my textbox allows multiline text, i didnt tried using client.DownloadString

Comment: I get same problem even with client.DownloadString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try checking the string you receive in a text editor that will show hidden characters, like Word or Notepad++.  You may be getting a line feed character that should instead be a Carriage-Return Line Feed.  If that is the case you can convert it like this.

```
Dim text As String = reader.ReadToEnd
TextBox1.Text = text.Replace(vbLF, vbCrLf)
```